# DB Tables missing in Script Wizard

Tags: windows, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to script some DB tables in SSMS's Script Wizard, but when I get to the *Choose Object Types* step, there are no tables, only a checkbox labelled *Tables*.  Anyone have an idea what is wrong here?  I have just installed a package called TurboData to try for generating test data.  It could be that, so I'll ask and check that out so long.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

If there are no tables listed under the Tables entry then either 1) there are no user tables in your database or 2) you don't have access to any of the tables.

Did you already do your data generation with TurboData?  If so, check for any errors that it might have thrown.

Comment: This used to work, it's not access, and there are tables in my database - I'm trying to script them after all.  I have never used TurboData before - I just wanted to try it.  It didn't work so I uninstalled it with no change in Script Wizard.